# Class Comparer<T>: Aim of existence the Explicit Implementations of IComparer.Compare

Tags: c#, comparison

Aim of existence the Explicit Implementations of IComparer.Compare in implementations of `Comparer<T>` class.
If I implemented the `public abstract int Compare (T x, T y)` what reason and where it may used the call of `int IComparer.Compare (object ObjX, object ObjY)`, taking into account that ObjX & ObjY must be possible to be cast to type T (in other case will be ArgumentException).

Line 12 & Line 13 will produce the same actions;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      IComparer iRefCommon = (IComparer)new BoxLengthFirst();
      object obj1 = new Box(2, 6, 8);
      object obj2 = new Box(10, 12, 14);
      int resulCompare = iRefCommon.Compare((Box)obj1, (Box)obj2); //line12
      resulCompare = (new BoxLengthFirst()).Compare(new Box(2, 6, 8),
             new Box(10, 12, 14)); //line13
    }
}

public class BoxLengthFirst : Comparer<Box> 
{
    public override int Compare(Box x, Box y)
    {
        if (x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length) != 0)
        {
            return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
        }
        .....
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public class Box : IComparable, IComparable<Box>
{
    public Box(int h, int l, int w)
    {
        this.Height = h;
        this.Length = l;
        this.Width = w;
    }
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int Length { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
     ....
    }
    public int CompareTo(Box other)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. If it is: "why is there a non-generic interface `IComparable`, when there is also the ("better"?) generic interface `IComparable<T>`?", then the answer is most likely: **backwards compatibility**. [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) were introduced in C# 2.0. The non-generic version pre-dates that and wasn't "removed" to not break any existing code. -- Same with `IComparer` vs. `IComparer<T>`.

Comment: @Corak Question was regarding what is the right strategy:
By Example, I need implement Comparer for some Generic Class ("new code"), in which case i will implement either interface IComparer<T> or class Comparer<T> (the Comparer<T> is more usefull).
If I need implement Comparer for some NonGeneric Class (legacy code), I will implement either interface IComparer or class Comparer.
I doesn't see' practical use , that I will implement  Comparer<T>, and after that will use for calling the "my Comparer" through "int IComparer.Compare (object ObjX, object ObjY)".
Did you meet with such cases?

Comment: @Corak Or at real life the situation another: After implementation of Comparer<t>, i can meet with soft (class) that can't use the  IComparer<T>, but can use the  IComparer ? It's very common situation or not?

Comment: The *usual* strategy is to implement both. Because it's so dead simple to do. If you already *have* the generic `Compare(T a, T b)`, then implementing the non-generic version can be as easy as `public int Compare(object a, object b) => Compare(a as T, b as T);`. When you inherit from abstract class [Comparer<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1), this "plumbing" is already done for you. -- Same goes for `IComparable` vs. `IComparable<T>` and the `Equality` interfaces and abstracts, too. If you have the generic, it's easy to get the non-generic.

Comment: Why even use generics instead of using non-generics that work on "all objects"? Plenty of reasons. The most commonly stated are type safety, code reuse and no boxing of value types. For a full overview see microsofts [programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) on that topic.

Comment: @Corak :) No, I my question was - If you have the generics (which "are type safety, code reuse and no boxing of value types"), why will you use the non-generics (that work on "all objects", but not type safety and etc.)?

Comment: Again: **backwards compatibility**. The non-generic version was there first. A lot of people wrote a lot of software *expecting* and *using* the non-generic version. Then later, the generics were introduced. Now the question was, what to do? Remove the non-generic versions? That would break all the previously written software. That's a big no-no. Not have a generic version of everything everywhere it's possible and makes sense? Then developers would either not be able to take full advantage of generics, or have to implement their own interfaces and classes seperately and all over everywhere.

Comment: So the compromise: keep the non-generic versions but also introduce the generic versions. With the caveat that now there are several ways to basically do the same thing. Which apparently causes confusion some times. -- But that's also nothing new. Think of `for(;;){}`, `while(){}`, `do{}while()` and maybe even `foreach(){}`. All similar ways to "repeatedly do stuff (until a condition is met or isn't met anymore)". -- so "why will you use the non-generics"? You probably won't. But maybe at some point you'll use a 3rd party sorting algorithm that does. So just implement it, it's basically free.

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Box a = new Box(1, 1, 1);
            Box b = new Box(2, 2, 2);

            int c = a.CompareTo(b);

        }

    }
    public class Box : IComparable
    {
        public Box() { }
        public Box(int h, int l, int w)
        {
            this.Height = h;
            this.Length = l;
            this.Width = w;
        }
        public int Height { get; private set; }
        public int Length { get; private set; }
        public int Width { get; private set; }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
             return CompareTo((Box)obj);
        }
        public int CompareTo(object obj1, object obj2)
        {
             return ((Box)obj1).CompareTo((Box)obj2);
        }
        public int CompareTo(Box other)
        {
            int results = this.Height.CompareTo(other.Height);
            if (results != 0)
            {
                results = this.Length.CompareTo(other.Length);
                if (results != 0)
                {
                    results = this.Width.CompareTo(other.Width);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I updated to include CompareTo(object obj1, object obj2)

Comment: Based on your implementation Box class, in case of your call from class Program (int c = a.CompareTo(b);) will be called 'public int CompareTo(Box other)'.

Comment: ...Continue
In case of call (obj b; box a) will be called at beginning the "public int CompareTo(object obj)" and after  'public int CompareTo(Box other)'.
In which case will be used your additional variant -  public int CompareTo(object obj1, object obj2)?

Comment: I added new method because I read you request and it wanted two objects for the compare.  I normally use the one object method because the linq OrderBy want the one object method as well as a.CompareTo(b)